# Why is my weights-file not working / not found?

Tags: pytorch, object-detection, yolo

I downloaded YOLOv7 from the github-page, trained it on a custom dataset, took the weights and trained it again on a different custom dataset. Both Trainings worked as expected.

Now I want to use the final weights for detection in new videos, but I get an error, when YOLO tries to load the weights (see message below).

- Edit: I found the answer to my question. The problem was in the path to my weights there were upper case characters. Turns out that they are converted to lower case and the file could not be found anymore.

Thanks @gspr for pointing me to the right direction.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "detect.py", line 195, in <module>
    detect()
  File "detect.py", line 34, in detect
    model = attempt_load(weights, map_location=device)  # load FP32 model
  File "/home/mahler/yolo/yolov7/models/experimental.py", line 241, in attempt_load
    attempt_download(w)
  File "/home/mahler/yolo/yolov7/utils/google_utils.py", line 31, in attempt_download
    tag = subprocess.check_output('git tag', shell=True).decode().split()[-1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Whether it is "possible to train YOLOv7 multiple times" is not a programming question – it's a question about a specific deep learning model. As for the actual programming problem you have, you need to tell what "the code" is. Moreover, read the error message! It clearly refers to some unexpected output from running `git tag`. Do you have any idea what the code is trying to do? Where are the weight files? Do you know how they're structured? What happens if you load them yourself?

Comment: I tried to load the file myself and found that the error came from a function only invoked when a file is not found. Then I realized that the path only allowed lower case characters and mine had also upper. Thanks